# Android how to pass class object in snippet in google map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on Android Google Map and I am using MapApiV2. I am able to show the map, user location, markers on the map. My problem is that I want to open an InfoWindow when user click on any marker on the map. I am able to open the window also but I need to show more data in the info video so I am trying to pass the my CustomClass object in the .snippet() methos but it except only string object. So I convert my class object to string by simply doing this (uv.tostring) and pass to snippet() method. Now on the other side when I trying to get the dat from snippet using marker.getSnippt(); I can not access my data from the string. So please suggest me how can I pass my custom class object to snippt so I can acces my get, set methods of custom class.

Below is my code 
My Custom class is:

```
public class UserVerifyer implements UserVerfierInterface{
    // <userPojo>
    // <frequency>0.0</frequency>
    // <message/>
    // <status>NOTOK</status>
    // <token>ey0dok0vozrhwhe98rt6ydbs</token>
    // <url/>
    // </userPojo>
    private String frequency = "", message = "", status = "", token = "",
            url = "";
    public static String statusOk = "OK";

    public void setFrequency(String freq) {
        this.frequency = freq;
    }

    public String getFrequency() {
        return frequency.trim();

    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message.trim();

    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status.trim();

    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token.trim();

    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url.trim();

    }
}
```

MyCustomInfo window class is:

public class CustomMarkers implements InfoWindowAdapter {

```
// private Context context;
// private String text;
// private Integer image;
private final View mWindow;
private final View mContents;

public CustomMarkers(Activity activity) {
    // this.context = ctx;
    // this.text = text;
    // this.image = image;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mWindow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.balloon, null);
    mContents = inflater.inflate(R.layout.balloon, null);

}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    render(marker, mWindow);
    return mWindow;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    render(marker, mContents);
    return mContents;
}

private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
    String title = marker.getTitle();
    TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle));

    if (title != null) {
        titleUi.setText(title);
    } else {
        titleUi.setText("");
    }

    String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
    UserVerifyer uv = UserVerifyer.class.cast(snippet);
    System.out.println("Sttaus in Marker= "+uv.getStatus());
    // uv.getStatus();
    TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPlace));
    if (snippet != null) {
        snippetUi.setText(snippet);
    } else {
        snippetUi.setText("");
    }
}
```

}

and I am adding data in marker like this:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(getMyLocation().getLatitude(),
                        getMyLocation().getLongitude())).zoom(17).bearing(90)
                .tilt(30).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        UserVerifyer uv = new UserVerifyer();

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(
                        new LatLng(getMyLocation().getLatitude(),
                                getMyLocation().getLongitude()))
                .title("Me")
                .snippet(uv.toString())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.user_loc)));
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomMarkers(RecomendationScreen.this));
```

Please suggest me how can I do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**
Instead of converting to string and dive into complexity,I would like to suggest you alternative approach to achieve the desired result in very efficient manner.

You can create a `HashMap<Marker, UserVerifyer>` ,and you can retrieve object of `UserVerifyer` by using `Marker` as the key.so you can easily put the data and retrieve the data from `HashMap`.

**Reference:**
Have a look at [this example](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html).It is performing exactly what I mean to say.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Answer (score 1):

MehulJoisar's suggestion of using `Map<Marker, YourModel>` is the usual way to work around the limitation of Android API v2, but there is also another way.

You may use [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) for your task. It adds `setData` and `getData` functions to `Marker` class, so your code would look like this:

```
    UserVerifyer uv = new UserVerifyer();

    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(
                    new LatLng(getMyLocation().getLatitude(),
                            getMyLocation().getLongitude()))
            .title("Me")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.user_loc)));
    marker.setData(uv);
```

and later in `GoogleMap` callback:

```
//String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
UserVerifyer uv = (UserVerifyer) marker.getData();
System.out.println("Sttaus in Marker= "+uv.getStatus());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I successfully import the library, but there is no method I am getting like marker.setData(uv); Please suggest me how can I do this.

Comment: @Shiv Sounds like you haven't changed imports from original `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker` to `pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.Marker`. Check out [Migration from Android API v2](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/#Migration_from_Android_API_v2).

Comment: Update: Imports are now... com.androidmapsextensions.Marker